# How can I save a value from a dynamic array in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, dynamic-arrays

EDIT: The problem has been solved, I was accessing data that had not been initialized because of the incorrect while() condition. I have changed it from OR to AND. It now works as intended. Thanks!

---

I am trying to find the intersection between two arrays in C++. I have written code that does what I want, but when I delete[] the arrays it breaks resulting in a floating point exception. (Division by zero?) How can I save the value I want, without causing a memory leak in my program?

This code works exactly how I intend it to work if I omit the delete[] statements, but I believe this causes a memory leak. It will return 1 if I omit the statement biggestIntersection = *(factorsa + i); What can I do to save the value at factorsa + i and subsequently delete the array to avoid a memory leak?

```
const int Fraction::findgcf(int a, int b) const{
    a = std::abs(a); //absoute value
    b = std::abs(b);

    int* factorsa = new int[a]; //dynamic array of ints to store factors of a
    int* factorsb = new int[b]; //dynamic array of ints to store factors of b


    int numFactorsa = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= a; i++){//iterate over the ints from 1 to a
        if(a % i == 0) {//if we find a factor of a
            *(factorsa + numFactorsa) = i;// and append that to the array
            numFactorsa++;
        }

    }

    int numFactorsb = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= b; i++){
        if(b % i == 0){
            *(factorsb + numFactorsb) = i;
            numFactorsb++;
        }
    }

    int biggestIntersection = 1;

     int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(i < numFactorsa || j < numFactorsb){//while we are in the bounds of the two arrays
        if(*(factorsa + i) < *(factorsb + j)){ //if the factor of a is less than the factor of b
            i++;                               //move the index of a up one
        } else if (*(factorsa + i) > *(factorsb + j)){ //if the factor of b is less than the factor of a
            j++;                                       //move the index of b up one
        } else {                                    //otherwise they must be equal
            biggestIntersection = *(factorsa + i); //so that is the new biggest intersection between the sets
            i++; j++;
        }
    }

    delete [] factorsa;
    delete [] factorsb;
    return biggestIntersection;
```

Comment: you got the condition wrong `while(i < numFactorsa || j < numFactorsb){` loops as long as one of the counters is within bounds (you want both). However, to know if this is causing the problem please include a [mcve]

Comment: `new[]` is a lot more trouble than it's worth as you're discovering here. Learn how to effectively use Standard Library containers like [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of doing raw allocations of C-style arrays with `new[]`. In C++ you're 100% responsible for memory management, so doing manual allocations means being careful to add in the corresponding `delete[]` calls at the right place and time. Standard Library containers can handle this for you.

Comment: @tadman yes I have a version of this function made with vectors and it works perfectly, however I am not supposed to use containers for this assignment.

Comment: @user463035818 Thank you, this has solved my problem entirely. Such a minor oversight, but with catastrophic results! Just another pair of eyes is all I needed. Thanks again!

Comment: One thing to note is you can use pointers as if they're arrays and it's a lot more readable: `*(x + y)` becomes `x[y]`, and `*(x + y) = z` becomes `x[y] = z`. That helps avoid simple mistakes caused by cluttered code.

Comment: @tadman I have heard that this can be dangerous, I don't exactly remember why though. However I choose this way of expressing my array because of how I read it in my head. I read it as "The value stored at the address of the 'x' array 'y' memory locations over is equal to 'z'." I can understand that it looks cluttered to some people, but that is just a little quirk I have.

Comment: If using an array-style reference or assignment is dangerous, then using the equivalent pointer version is dangerous, and vice-versa. The two operations are identical in terms of compiled code. The difference is that the array-style tends to be significantly less verbose and isn't as error prone, something especially relevant when doing multiple de-references: `a[b][c][d] = e` is equivalent to `*(*(*(a + b) + c) + d) = e` but would you ever consider using the latter?

Comment: @tadman great point that is much easier to deal with in terms of multi-dimensional arrays, I was unaware that both produced the same compiled code. Thanks

Comment: With most compilers you can ask to see the assembly output and this can often be very educational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem - and likely what is causing your error, though a minimal example would make it clearer - is that you're accessing memory you haven't initialized. This can produce unpredictable behavior.

`int* factorsa = new int[a];` doesn't set each `int` in that array to zero - the contents of the array could be literally anything. Later, in your first `for` loop, you do set the values for some array locations, but not all of them. And so in your final `for` loop, you have no way of knowing what you're going to output. It will depend on the more-or-less random contents of the memory location you asked `new` to provide.

(Also, as a comment notes, your `while` loop condition is wrong.)

Comment: @G Fetterman, Thank you! changing the condition from OR to AND is what solved my problem. I do agree that creating the array with far more space than I would ever need is dangerous, however I think I am staying within the bounds of initialized data by keeping track of how many elements are initialized with the variables numFactorsa, and numFactorsb. Do you know of any way mathematically speaking that I could create the array with only the amount of space that I need to store the factors? i.e. 10 has 4 factors, so I would need space for 4 elements.

Comment: To answer your question about figuring out the number of factors in advance, no, I don't know off the top of my head how you could do that without already doing a factorization.

Answer (score 1):

You really should be using std::vector.  Then you don't have to worry about cleaning up.

```
const int Fraction::findgcf(int a, int b) const{
    a = std::abs(a); //absoute value
    b = std::abs(b);

    std::vector<int> factorsa(a);
    std::vector<int> factorsb(b);

    int numFactorsa = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= a; i++){//iterate over the ints from 1 to a
        if(a % i == 0) {//if we find a factor of a
            factorsa[numFactorsa] = i;// and append that to the array
            numFactorsa++;
        }

    }

    int numFactorsb = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= b; i++){
        if(b % i == 0){
            factorsb[numFactorsb] = i;
            numFactorsb++;
        }
    }

    int biggestIntersection = 1;

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(i < numFactorsa || j < numFactorsb){//while we are in the bounds of the two arrays
        if(factorsa[i] < factorsb[j]){ //if the factor of a is less than the factor of b
            i++;                               //move the index of a up one
        }
        else if (factorsa[i] > factorsb[j])
        {                                              //if the factor of b is less than the factor of a
            j++;                                       //move the index of b up one
        } else {                                    //otherwise they must be equal
            biggestIntersection = factorsa[i];      //so that is the new biggest intersection between the sets
            i++; j++;
        }
    }

    return biggestIntersection;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am specifically trying to solve this without the use of containers.